ROS 2 Node not Shutting Down Gracefully
I'm running ROS 2 Humble on a VirtualBox Ubuntu 22.04 machine. Whenever I run a ros node (like the one in the ROS2 Tutorial and try to end it using Ctrl+C, the node spits out an error and then closes.
my_node
However, if I run a node that I did not write, like turtlesim, it closes gracefully.

turtlesim
I've tried running the node on a different windows machine running another VirtualBox Ubuntu 22.04 machine and had the same error.
